# Get the three word with regexpr

Tags: regex, r

I can only get the first `Adam`,the start positon,end position ,length,how can i get the other two Adam in text?

```
text <- c("Hellow, Adam!", "Hi, Adam!", "How are you, Adam.")
regexpr("Adam", text)
```

Comment: D you mean `gregexpr`?

Comment: `regexpr` gets them all. and so does `gregexpr`.

Comment: Please be more specific. What is your expected output? Have you looked at the examples for `regexpr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it works just fine, outputs starting index and length for each "Adam":

```
> text <- c("Hellow, Adam!", "Hi, Adam!", "How are you, Adam.")    
> regexpr("Adam", text)
[1]  9  5 14
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 4 4 4
attr(,"useBytes")

[1] TRUE
```

Output of `regexpr` is a structure, an integer vector of starting positions with additional attributes (`?attributes`).

```
x <- regexpr("Adam", text)
c(x[2], attributes(x)$match.length[2])
```

to access starting position and string length for the second match.